# Setting implicit instance variable for Scala's object

Tags: scala, implicits

I have a Scala object with a bunch of utility-methods, each method makes use of an implicit method parameter `s`

```
object MyObject {
 def a(implicit s:String) = ???
 def b(implicit s:String) = ???
 def c(implicit s:String) = ???
}
```

I don't like that fact that I need this `implicit s:String` in each parameter list. Is there a way to set the variable `s` only once (i.e. when object is first accessed). For a class I would do something like this:

```
class MyClass(implicit s:String) {
 def a() = ???
 def b() = ???
 def c() = ???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer is "No you can't".

Why? Because `s` is not a variable, it's a parameter. So it is not set at some point at runtime (say, on first accession), but resolved (because it is implicit) at compile time.

When you write `MyObject.a` in a part of your code, the compiler will check if, in the current scope, there is an implicit `String` definition, and will use that definition for `s`.

If you then use `a` in another part of your code, it will use the implicit definition in that scope, which may very well be different.

All this is verified at compile-time, so it is not related to when the methods are accessed at runtime (although when they are accessed may change the runtime value for `s`, if you have mutable implicits, which should be avoided).

If you always want to use the same definition for `s`, why not simply put this definition in your object? Or import it as an implicit:

```
object MyObject {
  implicit def myImplicitString: String = ??? //first possibility
  import MyImplicits.stringImplicit //second possibility, if stringImplicit is indeed defined as implicit
}
```

The bottom line is, if you don't want to pass the implicit as parameter, you need to have it in scope, and since your scope is an `object`, it must always be the same.

However, what's wrong with using a `class`? It gives you what you want (avoiding to repeat the implicit parameter) without changing much your calls (just use `new MyClass().a` instead of `MyObject.a`, or even `MyCaseClass().a` if you define it as a `case class`). If you have other fields in your object, you can always put them in a companion object to your class, to minimize the overhead at instantiation.